# Aura component behaving differently according to profile

Tags: aura, custom-metadata, customlabel, translation, user-profile

Hello I have this aura component, when I log as a system administrator, it shows perfectly translated and displays the expected values (I use custom labels for translation and custom metadata for the values to show)

->Component marked in red (carga de archivos)
[image: correct display and translation]

The problem is, when I switch profile, it doesn't display the translation nor the values

->Component marked in red (file upload)
[image: wrong values labels not translated]

all other parts of my page are translated and work OK, except for this component, are there any permissions I need to check? or maybe an ORG config?

Please help!!!

*Note: This component behaves ok in dev and QA sandboxes, but not in UAT

Comment: Turns out it was a cache thing, so... I'm a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a browser cache thing, yeah I know, I'm a noob...